# Jenkins URL doesn't work

Tags: apache, ubuntu, jenkins

At the moment, Jenkins is running in a main IP Address and now I want to change it to IPADDR/jenkins cause I wanted to run another website there.
I did the change from Jenkins Configuration "Jenkins URL" to IPADDR/jenkins but Jenkins is still accessible by the main ip address so I cannot host all the other websites cause everywhere I go, I got redirected to Jenkins.
Using ubuntu 16.04 w/ apache2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must configure your web server to act as a **reverse proxy**. Then it can

- relay requests to `/jenkins/...` URLs to Jenkins, and
- serve other URLs on top of that.

See the [Jenkins Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Apache) for details on running Jenkins behind a reverse proxy.

Comment: So basically something as reported under mod_proxy should be enough for that right? I just assign where I want the website to be accessible right?